# Mamp 3 - promble cant to set apache ports to 80 and mysql 3306

Tags: mamp

Plz help I dont know what to do with this problem

when i try to set,it show up an ERROR like

**There is a problem with the server ports. Each server must be assigned a unique port. Please check your configuration.**

Comment: Do you have another instance running that is using port 80 or 3306?  Open up a terminal and run `sudo lsof -i TCP:$PORT | grep LISTEN` to see what processes are using 3306 and 80

Comment: It show up like    lsof: unacceptable port specification in: -i TCP:
lsof 4.87
 latest revision: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/
 latest FAQ: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/FAQ
 latest man page: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/lsof_man
 usage: [-?abhlnNoOPRtUvV] [+|-c c] [+|-d s] [+D D] [+|-f[cgG]]
 [-F [f]] [-g [s]] [-i [i]] [+|-L [l]] [+|-M] [-o [o]] [-p s]
[+|-r [t]] [-s [p:s]] [-S [t]] [-T [t]] [-u s] [+|-w] [-x [fl]] [--] [names]
Use the ``-h'' option to get more help information.

Comment: I had the same issue and was able to fix it via Luke's answer below.

Answer (score 6):

You need to set the Apache and Nginx ports so they're different (not both 80).

Answer (score 2):

I was able to set port 3306 for SQL in the MAMP interface, and able to set port 80 for apache by editing the httpd.conf and changing 8888 to 80 on lines 48 and 182.

copied from Eric C [Error changing the ports in Mamp 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26512279/error-changing-the-ports-in-mamp-3) on a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure just changing it back to 8888 should not have any issues, especially since it is the default port number.  Furthermore, here is a great article explaining how to set up the subdomain in more detail.

http://www.grafxflow.co.uk/blog/website-server/setup-localhost-subdomain-using-mamp/